# RestKit base URL - directory following domain name

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, restkit

I'm trying to set my base URL for RestKit as `http://example.com/api` like so:

```
// initialize AFNetworking HTTPClient
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/api"];
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

// initialize RestKit
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];
```

However for some reason it only saves the domain `http://example.com` as the base URL and no following directories after it.

I can simply prepend `/api` in front of all my API path calls (e.g. `/api/events/active` instead of `/events/active`), but it would be a lot easier if I were to eventually work with different versions of the API like (e.g. `/v1`). Ideally I would be able to just change the base URL and not so much all the individual paths. Any ideas why I can't set the base URL correctly?

Thanks much!
-Ryan

**SOLVED:**

Base URL was previously stored as "http://example.com/api" and path was "/events".

Thanks to Paul's answer below the correct way is to store base URL as "http://example.com/api/" and path as "events".

Comment: Can you show an example request you make?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the hood `AFHTTPClient` uses `-[NSURL URLWithString:relativeToURL:]` to construct your URLs. If you look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLWithString:relativeToURL:) for this method you'll see that it expects a trailing slash. You can get away with this as [AFHTTPClient](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/1.x/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m#L243) seems to append this for you.

That just leaves us with this potential issue

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com/api/"];
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSURL URLWithString:@"/events" relativeToURL:baseURL] absoluteURL]);
//=> https://example.com/events
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSURL URLWithString:@"events"  relativeToURL:baseURL] absoluteURL]);
//=> https://example.com/api/events
```

If you prepend a forward slash it knocks off any path components and just uses the host part of the url. So make sure you don't prepend a slash in your paths